# How can I get file from FTP server?

Tags: security, cmd, ftp

I have found the security hole in website. I can to sign in throught anonymous account so I signed in. So I am trying get index.html from website and I receive following message: Illegal PORT command.

> Use port or pasv mode.

How can I get this file then edit and next upload modifited file again?

Comment: Your question is [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). - It would be on-topic on [su], but I guess it is answered there already. Please google your problem before asking.

Answer (score -1):

if you're administering an FTP server, it would be best for you to configure your server to support passive mode FTP. However, you should bear in mind that in doing so, you would be making your system more vulnerable to attacks. Remember that, in passive mode, clients are supposed to connect to random server ports.

Thus, to support this mode, not only should your server have to have multiple ports available, your firewall should also allow connections to all those ports to pass through!

But then the more open ports you have, the more there will be to exploit. To mitigate the risks, a good solution would be to specify a range of ports on your server and then to allow only that range of ports on your firewall.